# Drive appears twice, Recycle bin empties itself

Tags: windows-xp, recycle-bin

On my Windows XP desktop system, I have the problem that the recycle bin empties itself whenever I open it, i.e. recently deleted items are visible for a second, *with each file appearing twice*, then they disappear (and this happens only once). Occasionally I'd like to undelete stuff rather than dig out the backups, so it's quite annoying.

This started when I added a second HD, separating the Windows and data partitions onto separate HDs. I did that via a Linux boot CD and the dd tool, and had some problem getting the boot loader to work, but eventually I had what I wanted, except that the data partition E: (now filling the entire second HD) showed up twice in "My Computer", with two different drive letters E: and P: leading to the same file system, and the problem with the recycle bin (which applies only to deleted files from that partition, not C:).

I managed to remove the P: drive letter in the disk manager, but it's still accessible if I enter P: as address in an explorer window and the recycle bin properties show separate configurations for E: and P: - interestingly, the P: drive is *not* present when I start in safe mode.

The recycle bin problem persists.

Any advice other than reinstalling Windows?

Answer (score 4):

Right-click Recycle Bin -> Properties.

Is the "Space Available" for each of your drives sensible (ie, greater than 0)? If not, change it :)

(And maybe check whether the "Do not move files to the Recycle Bin" item is selected)

Be aware that those settings must be applied for *each* drive.

Comment: But does this explain the behavior he sees?

Comment: I'm just tossing ideas out there. The behaviour with regard to the Recycle Bin certainly appears consistent; I ignoring the other evidence because it may not be relevant  :}

Comment: No luck. However, an itneresting detail is that the properties dialog still shows the two separate "views" of the data partition as drives E: and P:

Answer (score 4):

The folder for the recycle bin could have been damaged.

If you delete the Recycle Bin folder and then restart Windows, the folder will be re-created and restore its functionality. Restart Windows and press F8 at the Windows Startup menu, and then select Safe Mode with Command Prompt.

Navigate to the correct drive prompt (normally `C:` and `cd C:\`). Then type these two commands, pressing Enter after each line:

```
attrib -s -h recycler
rd /s recycler
```

Then restart Windows normally and see if the recycle bin works.

Comment: This did not help. However, it might be an important hint that while the second "view" of the data partition is accessible as drive P: via the command line in normal mode, but not in safe mode.