# Windows 10 files disappear from recycle bin

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, recycle-bin, user-folders

I needed to delete a couple of folders. I deleted 2 of them, accidentally deleted a file I was not going to, went to the bin, restored the file, went back to deleting the folders, finished it, decided to check up the bin for any other files I could unintentionally delete. I opened the bin and right in front my eyes some folders and files deleted both previously and just a few moments before opening the bin disappear from it. HDD is not even nearly full. I did not delete the files with shift key or anything else that could lead to files not ending in the recycle bin.

Does Windows OS empty the bin automatically? Have not witnessed such behavior in all the years. The size of all files inside it was far less 100gb, and I had had 200 and 300 gb in the bin before without any problem.

Could not find anything useful anywhere, except [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/686626/some-files-not-appearing-in-recycle-bin) and [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/9972/drive-appears-twice-recycle-bin-empties-itself), which are only a little similar.

Comment: “Does Windows OS empty the bin automatically?” - No; However, depending on the size they might have been permanently deleted, if that happened depends on the amount of storage allocated to the recycle bin.

Comment: Apart from Ramhound's comments, kindly check if this can help you: [How to fix deleted files not showing up in the recycle bin?](https://www.auslogics.com/en/articles/fix-deleted-files-not-in-the-recycle-bin/)

Comment: @Ramhound Thought about it.  I have checked the bin's settings, but not sure how large those files and folders were, so can not say for sure. The max size there was <100gb, however, as I have already stated 200 and 300 gb in the bin were never a problem before.

Comment: @Sunny Can not restart my PC right now, and as I understand resetting the bin requires that. I have also checked the bin's hidden folder on my system drive. There are a couple of files that are not displayed in the bin but no folders that I deleted recently.

Comment: @ymdred16 - Doesn’t change the fact, files recently deleted, are not automatically deleted.

Comment: @Ramhound I am 100% sure there were no files larger than 2-3 gb neither in the bin nor among the files I have deleted today. Plus I was able to see them for a couple of seconds when I opened the bin. Was it like Windows decided to remove excess files on recycle bin opening? Pretty weird in my opinion.